# Could not allocate new OCI Handle of type Statement

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, mono

I am new in Mono and need to deploy my .Net web application on Linux and Oracle as database
When running my web application, I am getting intermittent error : 
**Could not allocate new OCI Handle of type Statement**

However when deployed to Windows this problem does not occur
Has anyone encounter this problem before?
Going through the internet says that I need commercial Oracle Client provider. Is this true? Or is my Mono version outdate? Thanks in advance

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Mono 2.10.8.1
- ASP.NET 4.0
- Oracle XE 10.2.0 installed in Ubuntu 12.04
- Oracle Database 11G Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit installed in Oracle Linux Server